# How to synchronize listbox items in two forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, synchronization

How to synchronize listbox items in form1 and form2 in C#?
Namely when i added a item in the listbox on form1, add it to listbox placed in form2 at same time.

Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: set them to the same databinding source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and best) way is to bind both the `ListBoxes'` (even 3, 4 or more) `DataSource` to the same one. We have to use `BindingList<>` instead of `List` to benefit the capability of notifying changes in collection.

```
BindingList<object> listData = new BindingList<object>();
listBox1.DataSource = listData;
public void ShowForm2(){
  ListBox list = new ListBox();
  list.DataSource = listData;
  Form f = new Form() { BindingContext = this.BindingContext };//Set BindingContext the same to synchronize tracking item in both listBoxes.
  list.Parent = f;
  f.Show();
}
//This is used to add new item to the source
public void AddItem(object item){
   listData.Add(item);
}
//This is used to remove an item from the source
public void RemoveItem(object item){
   listData.Remove(item);
}
//This is used to remove an item by index from the source
public void RemoveItemAt(int index){
   listData.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Try adding controls to your form yourself. Call the `ShowForm2()` to show the form2. Then try calling the `AddItem` to add some item to test. Normally we add a string as new item for the listbox (`AddItem("item string")`).